# Excel csv (ms-dos) comma separated file

Tags: excel, csv, export

Hello does anyone know how I can export a *.xlsx to a *.csv (ms-dos) comma separated file
I can only export with a ;  I am using Excel 2007

Comment: Can you use this trick? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/

Answer (score 4):

If you csv exported is delimited by semicolon instead of comma, you are probably running Excel on a system that uses the comma as decimal point. As it's hard to export numbers that way, a semicolon ist used as delimiter. For example, in Germany, csv means semicolon seperated.

You can try to run Excel on a computer that is set to english, that will probably export using commas as delimiters.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have no English system. Is there a other way to set Excel to EN? Or a script to convert it to the correct format?

Comment: The link above from Skip Intro seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file using File Save As and a file type of "CSV." The file type is selected in the dropdown list immediately below the box you put the file name in.